# Button background color is not showing properly

Tags: ios, uibutton

```
   [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:199/255 green:57/255  blue:46/255  alpha:1]];
```

I tried this code to set button background color, but it is showing gray color,assigned color is something else

Comment: just add `.0` after `255`

Comment: when you change this in view didload or else in anyaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your arithmetics:

```
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:199.0/255.0 green:57.0/255.0  blue:46.0/255.0  alpha:1.0]];
```

What your code does is perform an integer division of `199 / 255` which results in something like 0.78 floating point but since you have not specified it to be a floating point arithmetic operation the program treats it as an integer division and omits the digits after the decimal point, resulting in `0`. Same foes for the other 2 color components.

To make sure the operation is treated as floating point you should write `199.0` instead of `199` because that tells the compiler that you care about digits after the decimal point.

Strictly speaking it would be enough to only write either the divident or the divisor with `.0`. Both `199/255.0` and `199.0/255` will yield the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:199.0/255.0 green:57.0/255.0  blue:46.0/255.0  alpha:1]];
```

Comment: both answers are correct. I cannot accept both answers,

Comment: No,  I think you accepted first my answer then changed to other thats why I asked

Comment: That answer has more explanation, no other issues. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can try this solution..

```
[self.CompBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:118.0/255.0 green:183.0/255.0 blue:59.0/255.0 alpha:1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

i think this one helps you...